# Display link after complete countdown time

Tags: 7

I am using [Field Timer](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_timer) module.

Is there any option to display a link after finishing countdown ?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can achieve that using the [jQuery Countdown](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_countdown) module

**Example for development usage:**

*In this example, we display an alert box saying "You are done!" after counting down from 10...*

```
<?php
  echo '<div class="countdown">10 seconds!</div>';
  jquery_countdown_add(".countdown", array("until" => 10, "onExpiry" => "finished"));
  drupal_add_js("function finished() { alert('You are done!'); }", 'inline');
?>
```